# Show that there is a number between 1 and 1000 such that there is a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Show that there exists an integer $n \in S = \{1,2, \ldots, 1000\}$ such that

$$\prod_{i\in S-\{n\}}i!$$

is a perfect square.

I was thinking in trying to prove it by contradiction using the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: That probably wonÄt work well: There are $168$ primes below $1000$ and with only $1000$ choices for $n$ you could at most pacify $9$ of them ($2^{10}>1000$). Actually, this won't work if $i!$ wre replaced by arbitrary divisors of $1000!$, so you do need to make use of the factorial somehow.

Comment: There question read that there is an integer.. we don't know if it may work for something else, but there is some n.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First observe that

$$\prod_{n\in S}n!=\prod_{n=1}^{1000}\prod_{k=1}^nk=\prod_{k=1}^{1000}\prod_{n=k}^{1000}k=\prod_{k=1}^{1000}k^{1001-k}\;.$$

For odd $k$ the exponent $1001-k$ is even, so

$$\prod_{k=1}^{500}(2k-1)^{1001-(2k-1)}$$

is a square, and we need only consider

$$\prod_{k=1}^{500}(2k)^{1001-2k}=\prod_{k=1}^{500}2^{1001-2k}\prod_{k=1}^{500}k^{1001-2k}\;.$$

Now $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{500}2k=500\cdot501$, so

$$\prod_{k=1}^{500}2^{1001-2k}=2^{500(1001-501)}=2^{500^2}$$

is a square, and we’ve reduced the problem to considering

$$\prod_{k=1}^{500}k^{1001-2k}=500!\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{500}k^{1000-2k}\;.$$

Each of the exponents $1000-2k$ is even, so $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{500}k^{1000-2k}$ is a square. Thus

$$\prod_{n\in S\setminus\{500\}}n!$$

is a square.

Comment: Why did you substitute k for 2k-1? To make sure it is always odd? And you will always get even numbers?

Comment: Did you get the 500, for the 500 odd numbers?

Comment: @OrchidFibio: No, I just wrote $k^{1001-2k}=k\cdot k^{1001-2k}$ and pulled one factor of $k$ out of the product for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,500\}$: $$\prod_{k=1}^{500}k^{1001-2k}=\prod_{k=1}^{500}\left(k\cdot k^{1000-2k}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{500}k\prod_{k=1}^{500}k^{1000-2k}=500!\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{500}k^{1000-2k}\;.$$

Comment: got it! thanks!

Comment: @OrchidFibio: You’re welcome! (It’s a cute problem.)

Comment: $$\prod_{k=1}^{1000}\prod_{n=k}^{1000}k=\prod_{k=1}^{1000}k^{1001-k}\;.$$
How did you get to here?

Comment: @OrchidFibio: $\prod_{n=k}^{1000}k$ is the product of $1000-(k-1)=1001-k$ copies of $k$.

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{500}2k=500\cdot501$$
How do you know this?

Comment: @OrchidFibio: Standard formula for the sum of a finite arithmetic progression. Or just use the well-known special case formula for the sum of the first $n$ consecutive positive integers: $$\sum_{k=1}^{500}2k=2\sum_{k=1}^{500}k=2\cdot\frac{500\cdot501}2=500\cdot501\;.$$